# Iterating over result of django query

Tags: python, django

I have a django query that I need to iterate over the result of but it is EXCEEDINGLY slow...here is some code

```
query = <Model>.objects.filter(<filter settings>

results = rollup(query) #This function isn't super important, it's basically just summing over
#specific fields that have specific properties, emptying the rest, and maintaing a few, the 
#result is still a django query set
```

Now I want to do something like

```
for r in results:
   #do stuff..
```

I have tried using things like `prefetch_related` and I am not seeing very noticeable results.  Are there other improvements I can do to this query

Comment: have you profiled it?

Comment: have you tried threading?

Comment: How can we possibly know if there's anything to be done? You've abstracted out all the relevant information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filters are slow due to Django ORM architecture (you should create a lot of Python objects) because there's a large amount of results.

Either your request is not good, either it's a misconception or you could use Model.objects.raw() for direct SQL query (much faster 10x faster in some case).

You can also use a direct SQL query using the `connection` object but you have to deal with objects creation (or list or dictionnary) by yourself. I use this for a project and the query is 60x faster than Django one, and I use `dict(zip(myfieldslist, myresult))` to retrieve my result to be compatible with the template.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/